# SherlockDialogFragment inflate layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and a SherlockDialogFragment.
i have a little problem for my project,,i want to show other layout in sherlockdialogfragment,everything work well, my problem is,if i use imageadapter,as long as i know it should use "this" in imageadapter..but in public static "this" can't used,how can it be?? i don't understand how to show layout in sherlockdialogfragment..here is my problem..

```
 ((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
```

and here is my full code

```
  public static class MyDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {
        int mNum;
        static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
            MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
            int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
                style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME;
                theme = android.R.style.Theme;

            setStyle(style, theme);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
                    "Windows", "Blackberry" };

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pen_content, container, false);
    View gridView = v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    ((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
            return v;
        }

    }
```

what should i do to fix mycode...
thanks...

EDIT....my problem solved..but i ask one more....what should i do,if i want to result value from gridview event click?? i add setOnClickListener but i get error...

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
                    "Windows", "Blackberry" };

               View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pen_content, container, false);
           View gridView = v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
           ((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), MOBILE_OS));
            gridView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id) {
                     Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(),((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                   });
                    return v;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
```

So it is

```
((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),MOBILE_OS));
```

You seem to have a type mismatch, a `SherlockFragment` does not extend `Context`, which your ImageAdapter probably needs.

To *attempt* to answer your edited question:

```
((GridView)gridView).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                 int position, long id) {
                     Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(),((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                   });
```

You still need to use the GridView class when setting your listener. You should cast from the beginning like so:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

Comment: @ltvie no problem, you should take a look at java [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) so you have a better grasp of OOP.

Comment: @ltvie You should make a new question, but anyways, what error are you getting? I attempted to answer your edited question, but keep in mind, "reusing" a question is not optimal. If my edited answer does not work, ask another question.

Comment: no.your answer work well for me...ok.i will use new question if i ask again... thanks for your help....